# Reading and writing a file (in video or picture format)in C, from one transmitter to a receiver

Tags: c, file, opencv, video

I want to read some video or image from a memory in my transmitter and send to a server.I just want to know I have to use fopen function in C or openCV ?Or is there any way to read some video file and send it ?
also I want to remember each video has a Frame width and Frame Height.

Answer (score 1):

Hi openCV is library for real-time image processing.So if you want to intrested in playing video or image then go through the openCV for more information  related openCV go to http://opencv.org/

Or if you want to just video data from video file and send to server then go through the `fopen()` function.Please find more info for transmit video file at http://systemsdaemon.blogspot.in/2011/03/live-streaming-video-tutorial-for.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use OpenCV is you just want to send the file to a remote server.
You will need OpenCV or a photo/video library if you want to do some processing on the frames.

Comment: @HOsseiNSA Gstreamer for example, this is what opencv uses for streaming.

Comment: @HOsseiNSA Like I said, OpenCV is well suited for image processing